# Save value in bash array gives array[] not found

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

i have this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
PIDS=$(ls -la /proc | awk '{print $9}' | grep "^[0-9]*$")
PIDLIST=$(echo $PIDS | tr "" "\n")
counter=0
for PID in $PIDLIST; do
  KERNEL[$counter]=$(cat "/proc/$PID/stat" | awk '{print $14 }')
  counter=$((counter + 1))
done
```

I'm trying to save the content of `cat "/proc/$PID/stat" | awk '{print $14 }'` command in a named KERNEL array, given a position by a counter.

I have this error:

```
mitop.sh: 8: mitop.sh: KERNEL[0]=26: not found
```

What i'm doing wrong?

```
sistemas@DyASO:~$ bash --version
GNU bash, versión 4.2.24(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Licencia GPLv3+: GPL de GNU versión 3 o posterior <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

Comment: What if you add `declare -a KERNEL` before your `for` loop?

Comment: Using declare -> mitop.sh: 6: mitop.sh: declare: not found and i´m using version 4.X

Comment: Do you run the script with `./mitop.sh` or by some other way, for example `sh ./mitop.sh` ? It's important.

Comment: I am using sh ./mitop.sh

Comment: try `bash ./mitop.sh`

Comment: Doesn't give me that error.  Maybe you are missing the #!/bin/bash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am using `sh ./mitop.sh`

That is the problem. You're not executing the script with Bash.
You are executing it with `/bin/sh`, which is very different.
You need to run it like this:

```
./mitop.sh
```

Or like this:

```
bash ./mitop.sh
```

This last one is just for sanity check.
The recommended way to run shell scripts is with `./the_script.sh`,
to let the first line decide how it should be executed.

Also, the script can be written better, I recommend this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
kernel=()
for file in /proc/[0-9]*; do
  read -a fields < "$file"/stat
  kernel+=("${fields[13]}")
done
```